# How to select a speech synthesis voice in an application

Tags: c#, c++, .net, winforms, voice-recognition

I am a new in this world, I am fall in problem with some strange thing, I was change Windows 7 Text To Speech Voice to Ivona Brina my computer default voice, but when I run my program the voice is same as first MS ANNA,

AND

There is another problem when I speck to my program then it come double,

here is my full code in c#,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;


namespace VoiceRs
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
            this.button2.Click += new EventHandler(button2_Click);
            this.button3.Click += new EventHandler(button3_Click);

            foreach (InstalledVoice voice in sSynth.GetInstalledVoices())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(voice.VoiceInfo.Name);
            }
        }
        SpeechSynthesizer sSynth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        PromptBuilder pBuilder = new PromptBuilder();
        SpeechRecognitionEngine sRecognize = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pBuilder.ClearContent();
            pBuilder.AppendText(textBox1.Text);
            sSynth.SelectVoice("IVONA 2 Brian");
            sSynth.Speak(pBuilder);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button2.Enabled = false;
            button3.Enabled = true;
            Choices sList = new Choices();
            sList.Add(new string[] { "hello", "test", "it works", "how", "are", "you", "today", "i", "am", "fine", "exit", "close", "quit", "so", "hello how are you" });
            Grammar gr = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(sList));
            try
            {
                sRecognize.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
                sRecognize.LoadGrammar(gr);
                sRecognize.SpeechRecognized += sRecognize_SpeechRecognized;
                sRecognize.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
                sRecognize.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
                sRecognize.Recognize();
            }

            catch
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sRecognize.RecognizeAsyncStop();
            button2.Enabled = true;
            button3.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void sRecognize_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {


            if (e.Result.Text == "exit")
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + " " + e.Result.Text.ToString();
            }

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

and here is my full project : [ClickLink](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B49e3Nm_85LcdzFXSWtVV1ZOMGc/view?usp=sharing)
 please help, Thank you...

Here is the prove that I am Install IVONA 2 Brian
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try running this MSDN example and see if you are able to hear IVONA voice.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer())
    {
        // Configure the audio output
        synth.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();

        // Build a prompt
        PromptBuilder builder = new PromptBuilder();
        builder.AppendText("That is a big pizza!");

        foreach (InstalledVoice voice in synth.GetInstalledVoices())
        {
            VoiceInfo info = voice.VoiceInfo;

            // Select voice
            synth.SelectVoice(info.Name);

            // Speak the prompt
            synth.Speak(builder);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please see this that I am Install IVONA 2 Brian http://i.stack.imgur.com/MoJ5y.png

Comment: Ok great, I've updated the code, try this and share the results.

Comment: Looks like the voice is not getting picked up for some reason. Try reinstalling IVONA voice software.

Comment: This MSDN example should work. I used this same code on my Windows 10 machine which has two voices installed, Microsoft David and Microsoft Zira and it worked fine, would repeat the same sentence in two voices. Try out other different built-in voices or download some other voice and see it they work.